# Windows Task Scheduler Doesn't Run VBScript

Tags: windows, vbscript, automation, scheduler, job-scheduling

I am trying to automate a VBScript by using Windows Task Scheduler. However, I tried to use `cscript.exe` + `"C:\...\script.vbs"` but it didn't run. I also tried to directly run the same command in CMD (`cscript.exe "C:\...\script.vbs"`) and it worked.

What might be the problem?

**EDIT :**

I just tried to switch the setting to `"Run only when user is logged on"` from `"Run whether user is logged on or not"` and it worked. I am wondering if there is a way to make my task scheduled run even when the user is logged off.

Comment: "I am wondering if there is a way to make my task scheduled even when the user is logged off" - didn't you just discover how to do that?

Comment: After multiple hours searching and trying dozens of variations for this issue, this is finally what did it for me: it has to run when user is logged on... that's a pity, but there it is... I guess this is because my VBScript file is calling Excel (it refreshes data connections and calculates formulas before saving the Excel file).

Comment: @flo5783 You might want to try with my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34912755/4338329 below; then you don't need to choose "when user is logged on".

Comment: @lovechillcool I had tried it but it didn't work; the Windows session really did have to be logged in and open (or maybe just locked).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After hours of research, one of Blake Morrison (from Microsoft)'s blogs came up; it mentioned that

> **If running a .vbs / .ps1 script, try launching it from a .cmd / .bat script**

see [Help! My Scheduled Task does not run…](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Ask-The-Performance-Team/Help-My-Scheduled-Task-does-not-run-8230/ba-p/375528)

That blog also explains a lot of rules/tips when using Task Scheduler.

So please create a .cmd/.bat file that calls for your VBScript. For example: `cscript.exe YourScript.vbs` would be in your .cmd/.bat script.

Answer (score 4):

Write a batch file like this:

```
echo "Started!" > c:\foldergoeshere\log.txt
cscript.exe "C:\...\script.vbs" > c:\foldergoeshere\log.txt
echo "Stopped!" > c:\foldergoeshere\log.txt
```

Then schedule the batch file instead of the vbs. That will allow you to see what is happening that is preventing it from running.  Any error that you would have seen executing in the console (CMD), will be instead output to that log file between "Started!" and "Stopped!"

Comment: Use `>>` instead of `>`. Using `>` would overwrite previous contents.

Answer (score 3):

What's the hassle all about? I don't use .cmd/.bat and script works! (Windows7 here)
My VBS script (as a scheduled task) runs well on any scenario of these 4:

1. **c**script and option "Run only when user is logged on"
2. **c**script and option "Run whether user is logged on or not"
3. **w**script and option "Run only when user is logged on"
4. **w**script and option "Run whether user is logged on or not"

It's only that on the 1st scenario I encounter the black command window flashing on my screen.

Action settings:

[image: cscript]
or
[image: wscript]

My script, which simply creates a file:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
filename = "C:\Temp\" & Hour(Time) & Minute(Time) & Second(Time)
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(filename)
```

Comment: Did you try if it works when you logged off? btw, I am using Win Server 2012.

Comment: @lovechillcool - Yes, for me it works as it should. When `"Run whether user is logged on or not"` is selected, Task Scheduler successfully calls my VBS script via either, cscript.exe or wscript.exe, even if I am not logged in.

Comment: I suspect the issue happens when using Office applications, so the above script would be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Greg answered this https://superuser.com/a/816073

Basically you need to create 2 folders:

You have to create a folder (or two on a 64bit-windows):

(32Bit, always) C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop

(64Bit) C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop

Fixed the issue for me (and I could point to the .vbs file, not bat needed).

Comment: This solved my problem. I could run the .vbs by double clicking it, but not when scheduling it in Task Scheduler. After creating the \Desktop folder, it worked.  It almost gave me a heart attack

Answer (score 1):

The .vbs file is running invisibly, which is a consequence of running it with the 'logged on or not' option.

**You will not be allowed to interfere with a user using the computer**, which means you will be able to help yourself, but not others.

Please read the following text from the Task Scheduler Help menu:

**Task Security Context**

> You can specify that a task should run even if the account under which the task is scheduled to run is not logged on when the task is triggered.
>
> To do this, select the radio button labeled Run whether user is logged on or not.
>
> If this radio button is selected, tasks *will not* run interactively.
>
> To make a task run interactively, select the Run only when user is logged on radio button.

Answer (score 1):

Have experienced more than once that a VBScript running as planned task worked fine for months and years but suddenly would not work any more despite nothing was changed. Have tried to reactive the task using all the recipes given here and elsewhere, but no success. My workaround was to create a **new** planned task with all settings copied from the original one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

1. `cmd` as the Program.
2. ```
   /c start cscript //nologo "W:\Pathto with spaces\VBScript.vbs"
   ```

   - `/c` send the following to the cmd
   - `start` starts the next parameter
   - `cscript //nologo "W:\Path with spaces\VBScript.vbs"` self explanatory. Path wrapped in quotes to allow spaces in the filename.

     **Screenshot**

     [image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
AKA Window 7, But in my case i first cd to the dir and then ran the .bat file to execute the .vbs file

> 1. Go to start menu
> 2. Search for run
> 3. Once it opens, Type "shell:startup" and press Enter

You'll be directed to the Start Up folder. In this folder you can put create a .bat file which you want to execute the .vbs file (You'll do this in a special way)

> cd C:\the\path\were.vbs\file\located && wscript.exe start_app.vbs

What your doing is cd to the directory **cd C:\the\path\were.vbs\file\located**

And then run the .vbs file **wscript.exe start_app.vbs**